# Android project build failing after bintray sunset

Tags: android, gradle, bintray

I know that bintray service has been sunset starting May 1 2021, and dependencies that were in bintray repository won't be available now. Unfortunately I had to clear gradle cache and now I am facing with a build error for the dependencies that were hosted in bintray. How do I know what is the alternate for these libraries, at least for the google libraries.

Could not resolve com.gu.android:toolargetool:0.2.1.
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/guardian/android/com/gu/android/toolargetool/0.2.1/toolargetool-0.2.1.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/guardian/android/com/gu/android/toolargetool/0.2.1/toolargetool-0.2.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that bintray service has been sunset starting May 1 2021, and dependencies that were in bintray repository won't be available now.

They have more recently said that they will be keeping JCenter open on a read-only basis indefinitely.

> Could not resolve com.gu.android:toolargetool:0.2.1

According to [the project site](https://github.com/guardian/toolargetool) and [according to mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gu.android/toolargetool), version 0.3.0 is available on Maven Central. In your project's top-level `build.gradle` file, add `mavenCentral()` on a line before each of the `jcenter()` lines and upgrade your version from 0.2.1 to 0.3.0.

> How do I know what is the alternate for this libraries, at least for the google libraries.

Most of Google's libraries, such as the Jetpack, are from Google's own Maven repository (the `google()` lines in that top-level `build.gradle` file).

Comment: yes after commenting `//maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/riontech/maven" }` related stuff build is success